# Ключевое слово using при наследовании конструкторов (using Base::Base)

Tags: c++, qt

Пишу проект под Qt. Есть необходимость дублировать конструкторы родительского класса. Видел у Страуструпа способ использовать `using Base::Base` в классе потомке. В общем, два класса, базовый и потомок (using в потомке):

```
class Hopper {
    public:
        explicit Hopper(QWidget parent, int x, int y);
};

class HopperSrc : public Hopper {
    public:
        using Hopper::Hopper;
};
```

В этом случае получаю ошибку `Hopper::Hopper names constructor` и `no matching function for call HopperSrc::HopperSrc(/*params*/)`. Решил попробовать упрощенный вариант:

```
class A {
    public:
        A(int x) {}
};

class B : public A {
    public:
        using A::A;
};

void main()
{
    B b(5);
}
```

Тоже не работает с такими же ошибками, хотя на [GDB](https://www.onlinegdb.com/) все компилируется. Попробовал с++11 подключить. Дописал в `.pro` файле (использую Qt4), но безрезультатно:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x
```

Смотрел еще [здесь](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration), но примеры аналогичные.

Я, конечно, могу сделать так:

```
class B : public A {
    public:
        B(int x) : A(int x);
};
```

но хотелось бы разобраться.

Может кто-то подскажет, в чем может быть проблема или хотя б в какую сторону двигаться?

Comment: А вы на чем компилируете?

Comment: @VTT, из настроек сборки  `Mingw as GCC for Windows targets`

Comment: И какая версия у этого компилятора?

Comment: -std=c++0x - мало. Нужно -std=c++17.

Comment: @VTT, gcc 4.4.0 и target mingw32

Comment: @Chorkov, на [GDB](https://www.onlinegdb.com/) даже без 14-го компилировалось

Comment: Полноценная поддержка С++11 в вашем компиляторе отсутствует. Непонятно, зачем сидеть с таким старым компилятором, тем более на windows, учитывая, что уже gcc9 на подходе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Книга Страуструпа написана по версии языка C++11, используйте соответствующий компилятор с правильным флагом. Для GCC & Clang это `-std=c++11`, для Visual Studio нет отдельного флага, просто нужно отыскать ту студию, в которой началась поддержка наследования конструкторов (последняя поддерживает точно).

Comment: обновил компилятор, проблема ушла, спасибо